# FB API is not displaying the data from the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook

I'm having an issue here when trying to display data or get the data to work or at least be displayed in the console - I currently have a TypeScript React project where I want to display a Facebook page posts, which include the pictures and message/description.

By following other resources and else, I've found that Ad blocker blocks the API on loca host at least, thus I added js.src to the connect Facebook link, that has been the most noticeable change I've done to the code given by Facebook in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart and I've replaced some of the appId digits with **** just in case.

And this is line of code in the index.html:

```
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
    <script>
      function init() {
        FB.api(
          "/me",
          "GET",
          { fields: "id,name,about,posts{full_picture,message}" },
          function (response) {
            console.log(response.name);
          }
        );
      }
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: "713461583720****",
          autoLogAppEvents: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: "v16.0",
        });
        init();
      };
    </script>
    <script
      async
      defer
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      js.src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
```

I'm open to answering any questions, I'm super thankful for any respond  this thread gets, thanks!

Comment: What did `response` contain, what did the browser console have to say? Unless you logged in as a user beforehand, you don't even have an access token here, so you won't be able to make such API calls.

Comment: Unless your app had the public content access feature approved, you won't even be able to get the page posts using a user token, if you let the user log in to your app first. You will need to use a page access token - and that must not be exposed in public client-side code to begin with. You will need to make these API requests from the server side then.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm very new to this Graph API from Facebook, so I can get a bit misunderstood here, apologies for that, I'm guessing that `response` acts as a prop, for example, the code given to me when I select "Get Code" after I submit the request is: `FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET',
  {"fields":"id,name,posts{message,full_picture}"},
 function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
 }
);` but It doesn't appear to work, about the client-side - server-side, I'm not really familiar with that, I'm currently running my project of vite npm run dev, is that client or server? Thanks!

Comment: The code you have above is client-side code. Vite appears to be a build tool with basic web server capabilities as far as I can tell, but I don't know if that includes actual server-side scripting.

Comment: A request for `/me` can only work with an access token, either user or page - otherwise, the API won't know what actual ID this is supposed to resolve to.